# Count where last associated record has a negative attribute

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables, `conversation` and `message` (a conversation has many messages).

```
conversation:
  - id

message:
  - id
  - conversation_id
  - created_at
  - read (boolean)
```

I want to count conversations where last (ordered by `message.created_at`) message's `read` attribute is `false`.

Comment: Well: find the last message (per conversation_id) and check if its read = false

Comment: For each conversation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To just get the count as outlined:

```
SELECT count(*) AS msg_ct
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (conversation_id) *
   FROM   messages
   ORDER  BY conversation_id, created_at DESC
   ) sub
WHERE NOT read;
```

You do no need to include the parent table `conversation` here at all.

The subquery returns the last row per conversation (`"ordered by messages.created_at"`).
Details here:  [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
The outer query counts those where `read` is `FALSE`.

Alternative with [`NOT EXISTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS):

```
SELECT count(*) AS msg_ct
FROM   messages m
WHERE  NOT read
AND NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   messages m1
   WHERE  m1.conversation_id = m.conversation_id
   AND    m1.created_at > m.created_at
   );
```

Might be faster for big tables. You'd have to test with [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html).

Comment: @VladKhomich: Added an alt version.

Comment: @Mihai: [`NOT` is the negation operator for a `boolean` type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-logical.html).